# Grails on Tomcat - How to log raw HTTP request/response

Tags: tomcat, grails, logging

I couldn't find the way to configure my dummy tutorial Grails application to log all HTTP requests and responses accepted/generated by Grails server (actually - Tomcat). Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option would be to use tomcat's built in access logging.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve

Im using this myself, and it is quite configurable.

How to configure tomcat 6

```
 <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"  
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" pattern="common" resolveHosts="false"/>
```

Add this to the end of your server.xml config under the tag "Host".

Comment: I would bet on this choice if you describe how to make it work with Grails. Unfortunately Grails (when executing Grails run-app) perform some hidden magic to start Tomcat within its JVM instance, and god knows how to configure that thing in this case :(

Comment: download tomcat. add the valve config to server.xml. then type grails war. copy the war to the tomcat webapps folder. start tomcat. now do a couple of requests towards your app. and then check your tomcat logs folder for access logs.

Comment: A-ah, this actually ends up with running Tomcat itself. I was looking to trace in dev mode, which is "grails run-app". I afraid this is somewhat different.

Comment: well, run-app in grails also runs tomcat. It stands to reason that there should also be a server.xml file which you can edit or reference  some way. However, i have not done this myself.

Comment: according to the tomcat documentation, the server.xml should be located at `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml`so if you can figure out (ex through System.properties) what is the home folder of tomcat on startup. Then you can probably just add your own server.xml... probably... :) good luck, have fun.

Answer (score 3):

you could either use a Grails plugin: https://github.com/TouK/grails-httplogger or a Tomcat filter. 

If you use Tomcat 7, it is the RequestDumperFilter.
I prefer the RequestDumperFilter.

In short:

Install the Grails templates

```
    grails install-templates
```

Edit web.xml and add the RequestDumperFilter

```
<filter>
<filter-name>requestdumper</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RequestDumperFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>requestdumper</filter-name>
<url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Edit the log4j section in Config.groovy and add

```
debug   'org.apache.catalina.filters.RequestDumperFilter'
```

This should be sufficient.

If you need some more information, [here](http://jolorenz.wordpress.com/2014/03/12/logging-http-requests-for-better-debugging-of-the-rest-api-part-4/) you will find an extensive instruction.

Comment: It appears https://github.com/TouK/grails-httplogger is no longer a valid URL. Does anyone know if this library has been updated to support Grails 3?

Answer (score 0):

Such logging could easily be implemented as a filter - either a Grails filter (see http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#filters for description of those and an example logging filter), or as a standard servlet filter (an example can be found here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Servlets/LogFilter.htm).

If you choose the second option, you'll have to modify `web.xml` to include your filter. To do so, execute `grails install-templates`. This will copy standard `web.xml` to `templates/WEB-INF` directory in your project, and you can modify it there.

Comment: I've tried this (as servlet filter) in it does work, nevertheless some coding is required.